# Need use case or example for Spark’s Relationship to Hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I am reading Spark Definitive Guide
In the "Spark’s Relationship to Hive" section ..the below lines are give

"With Spark SQL, you can connect to your Hive metastore (if you already have one) and access table metadata to reduce file listing when accessing information. This is popular for users who are migrating from a legacy Hadoop environment and beginning to run all their workloads using Spark."

I am not able to understand what it means. Someone please help me with examples for the above use case.

Comment: Hive metastore contains information about Hive tables, including their location and data filenames. In case if you would like to process Hive data by means of Spark, it is sufficient to connect to Hive metastore and use that table abstraction provided by Hive from within Spark

Answer (score 0):

Spark being the latest tool in Hadoop ecosystem has connectivity with earlier Hadoop tools. Hive was the most popular until recent times. Most Hadoop platforms have data stored in Hive tables which can be accessed using Hive as a SQL engine. However, Spark can also do the same things.

So, the given statements mention that you can connect to Hive metastore (which contains information about existing tables, databases, their location, schema, file types, etc.) and then you can run similar Hive queries on them just like you would with Hive.

Below are two examples that you can do with spark once you can connect to Hive metastore.

```
spark.sql("show databases")
spark.sql("select * from test_db.test_table")
```

I hope this answers your question.